# How to configure Quarkus with MongoDB to run Integration Tests?

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache, quarkus-rest-client

I have a Quarkus v3.3 based app that uses MongoDB for the database (using Panache) and it exposes several REST services.  How can I configure Integration Testing so I can test the system as a whole works as expected?

I have tried various website links show how to possibly do this but I can't get any of them to work.  The current approach uses these extra dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-container-image-jib</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client-reactive</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client-reactive-jackson</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I believe this is supposed to build a docker image and then test using the REST client.

However at build time I get this error:

IllegalState No RestClientBuilderResolver implementation found!

Can someone explain how to fix this error?  And any links to complete Integration Testing with my setup would be helpful as well.

Comment: Are you trying to use the REST Client in the test code?